# Getting percentage from group by query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with my SQL. I created this query:

I don't know how can I get that result with one query. I know that to calculate percentage I have to multiply the value obtained in the counter by 100 and divide by the sum of the whole count. Can you help me?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to use a variable:

```
SELECT browser, counter, counter / @sum
FROM (SELECT browser, count(*) as counter, (@sum := @sum + count(*))
      FROM analyticsCbVisits v INNER JOIN
           analyticsCbPlatformsBrowsers pb
           ON v.idChatBotTrackOperation = pb.idChatBotTrackOperation INNER JOIN
           analyticsBrowsers b
           ON pb.browser_id = b.id CROSS JOIN
            (SELECT @sum := 0) params
      WHERE b.idChatBotTrackOperation = 33 
      GROUP BY browser
     ) x
```

In other database, this is simpler because you can use window functions.

Comment: @AlexObrien . . . That is not very helpful.  You should specify what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
set @csum := 0;
SELECT browser,counter,CONCAT(FORMAT(IF(total=0,0,(counter*100.0)/total),2),'%')  as  percentage FROM(
SELECT  browser, count(*) as counter,@csum := @csum+count(*) as total
FROM analyticsCbVisits 
INNER JOIN analyticsCbPlatformsBrowsers ON analyticsCbVisits.idChatBotTrackOperation = analyticsCbPlatformsBrowsers.idChatBotTrackOperation
INNER JOIN analyticsBrowsers ON analyticsCbPlatformsBrowsers.browser_id = analyticsBrowsers.id
WHERE analyticsCbVisits.idChatBotTrackOperation = 33
GROUP BY browser) t
```

Another way to solve it:

```
SELECT browser,counter,CONCAT(FORMAT(IF(total=0,0,(counter*100.0)/total),2),'%')  as  percentage FROM(
    SELECT  browser, count(*) as counter,(SELECT  count(*)
    FROM analyticsCbVisits 
    INNER JOIN analyticsCbPlatformsBrowsers ON analyticsCbVisits.idChatBotTrackOperation = analyticsCbPlatformsBrowsers.idChatBotTrackOperation
    INNER JOIN analyticsBrowsers ON analyticsCbPlatformsBrowsers.browser_id = analyticsBrowsers.id
    WHERE analyticsCbVisits.idChatBotTrackOperation = 33) as total
    FROM analyticsCbVisits 
    INNER JOIN analyticsCbPlatformsBrowsers ON analyticsCbVisits.idChatBotTrackOperation = analyticsCbPlatformsBrowsers.idChatBotTrackOperation
    INNER JOIN analyticsBrowsers ON analyticsCbPlatformsBrowsers.browser_id = analyticsBrowsers.id
    WHERE analyticsCbVisits.idChatBotTrackOperation = 33
    GROUP BY browser) t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Table1.Browser, Table1.Counter, Round((Table1.Counter/(Select sum(Table1.Counter) from Table1))*100,2) & " %" AS Percentage
FROM Table1;
```

this Query Works perfectly in Access. It should in SQL too. Give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`WITH ROLLUP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) to get the total count

```
    | Browser | Counter |
    ---------------------
    | Firefox |    2    |
    | Chrome  |    1    |
    | NULL    |    3    |
```

and calculate the percentages on application side.

However - If you just want to run the query and export the result, you can save the total count into a session variable in a subquery and use it in the outer select:

```
SELECT browser, counter, 100 * counter / @total as percentage
FROM (
    SELECT browser,
        CASE WHEN browser IS NULL
            THEN @total := COUNT(*)
            ELSE COUNT(*)
        END AS counter
    FROM analyticsCbVisits 
    INNER JOIN analyticsCbPlatformsBrowsers ON analyticsCbVisits.idChatBotTrackOperation = analyticsCbPlatformsBrowsers.idChatBotTrackOperation
    INNER JOIN analyticsBrowsers ON analyticsCbPlatformsBrowsers.browser_id = analyticsBrowsers.id
    WHERE analyticsCbVisits.idChatBotTrackOperation = 33
    GROUP BY browser
) t
WHERE browser IS NOT NULL
```

Here is a simplified demo: http://rextester.com/QAT75385

Comment: Paul, thanks for yur help! i really need your help :)
I'm trying your query in phpmyadmin but the column "percentage" return null every time..no sql syntax error, but the column is ull every time...what can we do? 
UPDATE: @total is every time empty...

Comment: @AlexObrien what is your MySQL version?